prometheus rest api to update scrape config
Is there any REST Post/PUT/other API to add below to prometheus scrape config?
- job_name: 'My Service'
  metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - '10.252.1.2:61'
      labels:
        role: 'mysvc'


AFAIK, there is no API to upload configuration remotely. You'll need to handle this by something outside of Prometheus, and then hit /-/reload endpoint to apply changes in configuration.

No such API provided by Prometheus since it is a core Prometheus server config  file. I can suggest following options based on my experience and you can see which one works best for you ->

Use Ansible to remotely manage the prometheus config file
Create an RPM for configs e.g. prometheus.yaml and other config files like rules and alerts
You can create a simple python based service running as a sidecar to create/update the prometheus yaml on that server. Python has yaml processing package which can be used to easily modify the yaml files. Not the easiest option but doable if you really need this.

Hope this helps!
